# Listening to an opened WebSocket and fetching incoming messages on the browser-side

Tags: javascript, websocket, tcp, web-applications

I'm struggling with something about WebSockets and I can't figure out why.

## A bit more context

On [this page](https://flusk-privacy-testing.bubbleapps.io/version-test), there is a Web Socket that is called "notify.bubble.is" that is provided by Bubble, a no-code tool that allows you to build web applications without code.

Existing Web Socket

[image: 1]

I'd like to listen to the messages coming from the server (and especially one that is "has-last-change-flusk-privacy...") and intercept them.

## The problem

I tried several things in order to listen to this WebSocket :

- Writing function 'onmessage' on the window.WebSocket object to log the message into the console (did not work)
- Creating a new WebSocket and connect it to the same address as the existing one (wss://notify.bubble.is) but it receives no messages
- Overriding prototype of window.WebSocket object to rewriting the 'onmessage' function (did also not work)
- Adding an EventListener to the document with event 'onmessage' but it receives no messages

So I'm a bit confused...
I'm 99% sure there is a way to fetch these messages, and I think you guys could have wonderful and maybe out-of-the-box ideas (or maybe it's very easy and I'm just so bad)!

If you need more details, more info, or anything... just ask and I'll answer as soon as I can.
Thanks, guys! :)